# Is `badblocks` meaningful on compact flash cards?

Tags: crash, bad-sectors, filesystem-corruption, bad-blocks, compact-flash

I own ten (10) compact flash cards. The cards are industrial high quality ones. Because of some random system crashes I checked all 10 cards using `badblocks`:

```
sudo badblocks -w -s -o badblocks-card1.log /dev/sdb
```

Badblocks reported for nine out of ten (9/10) hundreds of bad blocks. Does this really mean, that those nine cards should *not* be used anymore and need to be replaced? Or is there any protection layer in kernel (or on the card) which normally corrects those bad blocks and I do not have to care about them?

**Is `badblocks` really that meaningful on compact flash cards?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`badblocks` is meaningful on any storage device.
It's a very simple program that just reads (and optionally writes)
the entire disk, counting how many errors occurred while doing so.

You have apparently bought a bunch of bad ones.
Use at your own risk.